# Structural Topic Modeling in R: group the topics deductively and estimate effect

Tags: r, text-mining, topic-modeling

The stm package in R allows the user to estimate the relationship between metadata and topics. I have a model M with 40 topics, and I want to explore how they change with time. In stm, it should be something like this (adapted from Molly Roberts et al., stm: R Package for Structural Topic Models):

```
prep = estimateEffect(1:40 ~ s(day), M, meta = out$meta, uncertainty = "Global")
```

This command will return 40 pairs of relationships, each refers to one topic. However, upon reading the topics I found it makes theoretical sense to group some of the topics together and reduce the number of topics. Is there a way of grouping the topics manually?

Comment: There isn't right now, but we are working on it.  My advice would be to do the calculations yourself in the interim. If you consider the case of uncertainty="None", estimateEffect is just running a regression.  If you want to fold in the uncertainty, you can use thetaPosterior() to get the draws.  Depending on your programming background that might be a lot which is why we want to build in this functionality in the future, but we aren't there yet!