# Structural topic modeling (STM): reduce number of topics in R

Tags: r, aggregate, text-mining, topic-modeling

My question is conceptual and relates to this question [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48657585/structural-topic-modeling-in-r-group-the-topics-deductively-and-estimate-effect) on the calculation of estimate effects.

When doing structural topic modeling (using the stm-package in R), I have the option to pre-set a number of topics into which the corpus is to be divided (K=x), or to let the program calculate inductively the number of topics (set K=0).

What is the process to find the sweet spot for a number of topic that makes substantial sense, not just statistical? **How do I aggregate topics that I believe are in fact one, but which the K = 0 algorithm sees as different ones?**

As I understand it, there are multiple options:

1) Approach the "sweet spot" by repeatedly *changing the fixed number of topics* (K=20, K=25, K=30...).

2) Try to reduce the number of topics by *including additional stop words*.

3) Take the output from K = 0 and *aggregate the topics manually by counting them as one*.

Which one is best practice?

Comment: This is a methodological question rather than a programming question, so maybe posting it on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ would make more sense. As far as I know it is also an unsolved methodological question which people still research/debate and the three options above seem to be the ones available right now, so good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the suggestions, @JBGruber.